# How to parse Json.stringify() in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am beginner for ionic apps development and i am trying **store** and **get** json data using below code but using below code when i call get method i am getting undefined message can some one help me please

### code:-

```
save(){
    var usertostore = {"id": 1234, "info":"fdsgf"};
    this.storage.set("userLoged",JSON.stringify(usertostore ))
  }

 get(){
    this.storage.get('userLoged').then(status=>{
      var userInfo = status;
      alert("info is-->"+userInfo.info)
    });
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify/JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way how you **[parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**,

```
 var userInfo = JSON.parse(status);
```